# Reading properties with Constretto

Tags: java, configuration

In the [documentation](https://github.com/constretto/constretto-core) the authors give the following example:

```
@Before
public void prepareTests() {
    setProperty("datasources.customer.url", "jdbc://url");
    setProperty("datasources.customer.username", "username");
    setProperty("datasources.customer.password", "password");
    setProperty("datasources.customer.vendor", "derby");
    setProperty("datasources.vendor", "derby");
    setProperty("datasources.customer.version", "10");

    configuration = new ConstrettoBuilder().createSystemPropertiesStore().getConfiguration();
}

@Test
public void createNewAnnotatedConfigurationObject() {
    DataSourceConfiguration customerDataSource = configuration.at("datasources")
        .from("customer").as(DataSourceConfiguration.class);

    assertEquals("jdbc://url", customerDataSource.getUrl());
    assertEquals("username", customerDataSource.getUsername());
    assertEquals("password", customerDataSource.getPassword());
    assertEquals("derby", customerDataSource.getVendor());
    assertEquals(new Integer(10), customerDataSource.getVersion());
}
```

However, the `ConstrettoConfiguration` class doesn't seem to have a `at()` or `from()` methods at all.

Anyone using this framework and knows how to achieve the same effect in the existing implementation?